# Find elements by class name C# Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm new at C# and I'm trying to get elemnts by their class name. I found a way with the Xpath, but I'm sure there is more elegant and suitable solution to it.

First I'm "grabbing" the table and then I'm finding the elements by Xpath. The thing I want to to do is to define one row. For example `entireRow` and through it to distribute the the different type of elements into two sums. If element is with class `"devColorLower"`,  `+=devColorLower` value,  if elements is with class `"devColorUpper"`, `++devColorUpper` value.

Here is the code I use.

```
// Grab the table
var tbody1 = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@id='DataTableID']/tbody/tr"));

// Grab the color values
foreach (var row in tbody1)
{
    var entireRow = row.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td"));
    var shortfall = row.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td[@class='DataTableTD devColorLower']")); 
    var exceedence = row.FindElements(By.XPath(".//td[@class='DataTableTD devColorUpper']"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've reached to conclusion. I've added second foreach cycle

```
 foreach (var cell in entireRow) // Defines a foreach cycle that check every cell in the row - entireRow
            {
                String cellClass = cell.GetAttribute("class"); // Gets the class 

                if (cellClass == ("DataTableTD devColorLower")) { ..code}
```